# Proxy around a Writable stream cause `write after end` errors when piping data

Tags: node.js

I want to create a wrapper around a Writable stream. But when I try to `pipe()` some data through that proxy, I end up having *write after end* errors.

Here is a self-contained example showing my problem:

```js
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const { Writable, Readable } = require('stream');

class MyStream extends Readable {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this._iterator = this.generator();
  }

  *generator() {
    for(const c of "Hello")
      yield c;
  }

  _read(n) {
    const it = this._iterator.next();
    if (it.done)
      this.push(null);
    else
      this.push(it.value);
  }
}

class Proxy extends Writable {
  constructor(req) {
    super();
    this._node_req = req;
  }

  end(chunk, encoding, cb) {
    console.trace("end");
    this._node_req.end(chunk, encoding, cb);
    return {}; // return something
  }

  _write(chunk, encoding, cb) {
    console.log("_write", chunk.toString("utf8"));
    return this._node_req.write(chunk, encoding, cb);
  }
}

const src = new MyStream()
const req = http.request("http://httpbingo.org/post", { method: "POST" }, (res) => {
  res.pipe(process.stderr);
});
src.pipe(new Proxy(req));
```

Here is the dump of what I obtain when I run this program:

```
sh$ node --version
v14.17.1
sh$ node t.js
_write H
Trace: end
    at Proxy.end (/home/sylvain/Projects/getpro/t.js:33:13)
    at MyStream.onend (internal/streams/readable.js:665:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:481:28)
    at MyStream.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
_write e
events.js:352
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_http_outgoing.js:694:15)
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:706:5)
    at ClientRequest.write (_http_outgoing.js:687:15)
    at Proxy._write (/home/sylvain/Projects/getpro/t.js:40:27)
    at doWrite (internal/streams/writable.js:377:12)
    at clearBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:529:7)
    at onwrite (internal/streams/writable.js:430:7)
    at callback (internal/streams/writable.js:513:21)
    at afterWrite (internal/streams/writable.js:466:5)
    at onwrite (internal/streams/writable.js:446:7)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at writeAfterEndNT (_http_outgoing.js:753:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21) {
  code: 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END'
}
```

While investigating this issue, I noticed I can fix it for file streams by forwarding the proxy's `_write` to the original object's `_write` method (and not `write` without underscore as showed in the code above).

Unfortunately, the HTTP request object does not have a `_write` method. So I wonder if I can proxy it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyStream` will push data as fast as possible into its internal buffer, and emit an `end` event when it's done. This in turn calls `Proxy.end()`, as explained [here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readablepipedestination-options):

> By default, stream.end() is called on the destination Writable stream when the source Readable stream emits 'end', so that the destination is no longer writable.

However, the writable will still receive calls to `_write()` because the readable's buffer may not have been drained yet. Because you already ended the HTTP request in `end()`, you get a message that you are trying to write to an ended writable.

Overriding [`writable._final()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#writable_finalcallback) is probably a better way to end the HTTP request:

```
class Proxy extends Writable {
  …
  _final(callback) {
    this._node_req.end(callback);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Robert. Apparently, calling `._node_req.end()` from `_final` solve the issue. I must admit it is not entirely clear (1) why in the original implementation `end()` was called immediately after the first read and was not queued (2) why and how exactly `_final()` is called. I will do more experiments tomorrow.

Comment: :/ After more thorough testing, it appears your solution works in the minimal example I gave in the question, but on the other hand `_final` does not seem to be called in the real app.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux not sure why that is. _Possibly_ it works better with `_destroy()` instead of `_final()`, but that would just be guessing.

Comment: I found the problem, @robert: I overload `end()` in the proxy, but I forgot to call `super.end()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the pipe(res) is triggered on each data event. By the time your second data event occurs, the res stream is already closed.
You have to override the end method.
This code works:

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const { Writable, Readable } = require('stream');

class MyStream extends Readable {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this._iterator = this.generator();
  }

 // __proto__;

  *generator() {
    for(const c of "Hello")
      yield c;
  }

  _read(n) {
    const it = this._iterator.next();
    if (it.done)
      this.push(null);
    else
      this.push(it.value);
  }
}

class Proxy extends Writable {

  constructor(req) {
    super();
    
    this._node_req = req;
  }

 // __proto__;

  end(chunk, encoding, cb) {
    //console.trace("end");
    //this._node_req.end(chunk, encoding, cb);
    return {}; // return something
  }

  _write(chunk, encoding, cb) {
    console.log("_write", chunk.toString("utf8"));
    this.prototype = new Writable();
    this.prototype.constructor = Writable;
    return this._node_req.write(chunk, encoding, cb);
  }

  _final(callback) {
    this._node_req.end(callback);
  }
}

const src = new MyStream()
src.pipe(new Proxy(fs.createWriteStream("out.tmp")));
```